Which powers or abilities does Beelzebub get when he "absorbs the power of darkness"?
In the anime, we see several times Beelzebub in the night, he extends his arms outdoors, and we're told he does that to "absorb the power of darkness". But as far as I remember, we never see which powers or abilities he gets by doing that.
Which powers or abilities does Beelzebub get when he "absorbs the power of darkness"?

I guess there is nothing specific about Beelzebub's abilities, so it is like he increased his ki by that.

does people in Sand Land have ki?

No, I mean, power of darkness itself is the ki for Beelzebub. Either way, I don't think it is explicitly described and the question seems unanswerable.
